# Adding if statement to an existing while loop

Tags: bash, scripts

I have to do add an if statement to my while loop.

When I write `./scriptname 1`, it executes my while loop.
When I instead write `./scriptname hello`, it still executes my while loop.

What I want it to do is `echo "no"` if I add letters after `./scriptname` but execute the while loop if I add numbers after `./scriptname`.

Does anyone know what I have done wrong in the script attached?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text - copy and paste the script into your question using the [edit] button and format it as code using the markdown tools provided

Comment: it should be ```x=$1``` and its  better to test other way around, for non-digit ```[[ ! $x =~ [^0-9] ]]```

Answer (score 1):

Its a good practice to keep your if-then-statement as short as possible, this way you dont need the `else` statement.

```
#!/bin/bash

x=$1
y=$2

if [[ $x =~ (^$|[^0-9]) ]]; then
    echo "no"
    exit 0
fi
while (( $x <= 3 )); do
    echo "$x $y"
    ((x++))
    sleep 5
done
```

Or with a for-loop:

```
for ((z=3; $x<=$z; x++)); do
    echo "$x $y"
    sleep 5
done
```